# I am creating new product from admin in shopware but it's not appearing in frontend

Tags: admin, product, shopware

I am creating product from admin in shopware I have filled almost all required detail.
[image: screenshot]

But I am getting in frontend  **Unfortunately, this product is no longer available**.

Comment: Did you assign a category to the product?

Comment: Yes i have assigned category

Comment: Try to clear the cache 

probably the new article is not in the frontend cache

Comment: Please check also the list view (articles -> overview) and activate "show variants". There are two checkboxes for the active state and both have to be set.